# What is a scalar particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin

I was studying particle physics and I saw the word "scalar particle" many times, also in books. On the internet there wasn't any thing about it.

So can anyone say what is a scalar particle ?

Comment: The most famous scalar particle in string theory is the tachyon. There is also the dilation, a massless scalar particle.

Answer (score 18):

In short (and not very accurately) – a scalar particle is a particle that has no spin and no ‘inner structure’ that requires its field operator to have representation in terms of different components.

More accurately – the particles are excitations of fields, and when we construct these fields we have to ask ourselves how do they transform under rotations and boosts, which together form the group of Lorentz transformations. When analyzing the different ways that fields can transform under these transformations, the most basic and ‘simple’ type is the scalar, which is invariant and remains the same regardless of rotations and boosts. The particles that behave like this under the Lorentz group are then scalar particles. Similarly, we have spinors (such as electrons) and vectors (such as photons), which transform differently when we rotate the coordinate system or preform a boost operation.

Comment: The Higgs is an example of a scalar field, also called a “spin 0 boson”.

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange. Thank you for the great answer. Can you please give an example of a scalar particle?

Comment: @Andrea thanks. Your comment and my request for an example of a scalar particle came simultaneously!!

Comment: @AmeyJoshi I think that for the fundamental particles (that are in the standard model) only the Higgs boson is a scalar particle. However, I think that there are composite particles (Mesons) that are scalars. For example the Pions (I think?)

Comment: I think it's a little awkward to call photon a vector. Since there is a distinction between a gauge spin 1 boson and a true vector boson. Or am I just wrongly informed about the naming convention?

Comment: @DvijMankad I could be wrong about the nomenclature but the photons are excitations of the gauge fields $A_\mu$ that behave like vectors. So I would say they are vectors.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's fair because they are after all in the vector representation of the Lorentz group. I just feel hesitant because the field of operators $A^\mu$ is not like a usual vector field but is rather constrained by the Ward identities. I would call them gauge vector bosons rather than vector bosons but I think it's just me being pedantic in a way that has no bearing on the transformation properties of $A^\mu$ under the Lorentz group.

Comment: I am not a particle person, but I would be very surprised if photons were not exactly vector particles. The Electric field is vector, a photon has three orthogonal polarisation states (as a spin 0 particle) connecting to the 3 orthogonal polarisation directions (in a linear basis Ex, Ey, Ez).

Comment: @yu-v, your definition does NOT differentiate between a scalar and a pseudoscalar.  You have to add parity into the mix (say reflection, not constrained to *special* Lorentz rotations/boosts) to make the definition non-ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Scalar particles are those which have total angular momentum is 0 and parity even (+).